# Call variable from cherrypy webhook class

Tags: python, python-3.x, cherrypy, python-telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I set webhook to my telegram chatbot with the help of CherryPy. And now I am trying to handle data which I receive through webhook. I found the variable in cherrypy webhook class which contains needed json data. In my code, the variable name is **json_string**. I need to call this variable everywhere in my python script. How I can do that? Thanks.

```
class WebhookServer(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        if 'content-length' in cherrypy.request.headers and \
                        'content-type' in cherrypy.request.headers and \
                        cherrypy.request.headers['content-type'] == 'application/json':
            length = int(cherrypy.request.headers['content-length'])
            json_string = cherrypy.request.body.read(length).decode("utf-8")
            update = telebot.types.Update.de_json(json_string)
            bot.process_new_updates([update])
            return ''
        else:
            raise cherrypy.HTTPError(403)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider simplified HTTP handler where json is automatically decoded into dict by `json_in` Tool and the result is stored in `cherrypy.request.json`.

You may write some function in an external module, say `utils.py`, import it along with your server code and pass that data in:

==>> `your_server.py` <<==

```
from utils import process_telegram_webhook

class WebhookServer(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    @cherrypy.tools.json_in()
    def index(self):
        req = cherrypy.request
        incoming_dict_object = req.json
        process_telegram_webhook(incoming_dict_object)
        return ''

# ...
```

==>> `utils.py` <<==

```
def process_telegram_webhook(data):
    # ... do smth with json data from telegram:
```